# Stop another app's media player when i play new app's media player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

hello i am working on new music media player when i play song then not stop or not pause another app's media player like i have two apps 1) "gannna" and another is my app. When i play song in my app's media player then not stopping "ganna"'s media player song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your app starts playing audio it should request—and receive—the audio focus. Likewise, it should know how to listen for a loss of audio focus and respond appropriately when that happens.

You can achieve this functionality by 'Managing Audio Focus'. These Links may help you

https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html

Comment: Hello @Reena i have two different app with media player so it's works for me?

Comment: Hey please read this link https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html carefully. Audio Manager handles events itself.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/src/com/example/android/musicplayer?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F

Comment: Thank u @Reena it's work for me

Comment: Hey wolud be great if you will accept my answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130181/discussion-between-robbypatel-and-reena).